# Passar ID para modal através do ng-repeat AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, angular

Como pegar o ID (prod.produtoId) da linha no ng-repeat e passar para modal para atualizar o registro. Deve ser algo com ng-click no button mas não estou encontrando nenhum exemplo. Alguém poderia de dar um auxilio. Obrigado!

```html
<tr ng-repeat="prod in produtos">
  <td class="text-center">{{prod.produtoId}}</td>
  <td class="text-center">{{prod.produtoOperadora}}</td>
  <td>{{prod.produtoDesc}}</td>
  <td>{{prod.produtoPreco | currency}}
    <td>{{prod.produtoPrecoConv | currency}}</td>
    <td class="text-center">
      <button id="btn" class="btn btn-info btn-sm text-white" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#updateProd">
                                    <i class="fa fa-refresh"></i>
                                </button>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 1):

Para enviar o id para um método no seu js é só colocar o click e chamar um método passando o prod.produtoId como parâmetro.

```
<button id="btn" class="btn btn-info btn-sm text-white" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#updateProd" ng-click="editar(prod.produtoId)">Editar</button>
```

No js

```
editar: function(id){

}
```

Como o button está dentro da sua estrutura de repetição ele irá pegar o id correspondente a linha da sua tabela.